# Performance issue using a istringstream

Tags: c++, file, parsing, csv, stream

I'm parsing a large CSV file (~450 MB). The parser is based on `ifstream` and `getline`. This works really well, but takes some time. To reduce the time, I tried to read a compressed version of the CSV file (~ 21 MB) into a `istringstream` and use the same parser. However, the parser takes the same amount of time when using an ifstream or an istringstream. In my understanding the parser should be faster when an istringstream is used, because the content is already buffered in memory.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
ifstream file(filename)
istream* filePointer = &file
if(gz file) {
    read file into string
    decompress string
    create istringstream from decompressed string
    set filePointer to istringstream
}
parse(filePointer)
---
void parse(istream* file) {
    // ...
    while(getline(*file, line)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Performance results:

- uncompressed

  - parser: 15 s (ifstream)
- compressed

  - read file and decompress: 4 s
  - parser: 15 s (istringstream)

Is this normal behaviour, that  the `istringstream` is not faster than reading and parsing the file simultaneously using `ifstream`?

Comment: How did you know/ensure that the uncompressed input was not buffered in OS filesystem cache memory before processing it?  That could easily hide the disk I/O overheads.  It's also possible that the input's being "read ahead" efficiently in the background concurrently with your parsing, such that there's more data ready in time; they can't necessarily be expected to simply add together.

Comment: Your results merely indicate that the disk IO is not the bottleneck but probably the CPU/parser algorithm.

Comment: If you think that replacing the filesystem with memory resource can do any performance improvements, then I'd suggest that you read more about today operating systems - because this might have been true at latest 20 years ago. Today OS balances the use of physical fs and memory as it sees fit, and they have nothing to do with the program's use of memory (programs alloc/dealloc) and fs (using filenames, read/write etc.). May happen that using mem instead of fs may cause increased use of... fs (by the OS) due to swapping. OTOH files are also "cached" in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in your performance results, the parsing time is constant, and as such, both methods read the file faster than it is getting parsed. Thus the speed bottleneck is the parsing itself, and reading the file any faster will not help with performance. If you want to further optimize your code, you need to do something to the parser.